Timer countdown starts from wrong value on initial start but works correctly afterward
I'm working on a Verilog project where I have implemented a countdown timer using preset counters. However, I'm encountering a strange issue when I set a time and start the countdown. On the initial start, the timer begins counting down from the wrong value, but after that, it functions correctly. Here's what happens:
If I set the timer to 1 minute, the countdown starts from 1 minute 59 seconds instead of 1 minute.
If I set the timer to 10 minutes, it starts from 19 minutes 59 seconds instead of 10 minutes.
If I set the timer to 1 hour, it starts from 1 hour 59 minutes instead of 1 hour.
After this initial incorrect behavior, the timer works as expected for subsequent countdowns. I suspect the issue has something to do with the preset values or how the timer initializes, but I'm not sure how to fix it.
//Timer Module
module timer(KEY,SW,oCNT0,oCNT1,oCNT2,oCNT3,oCNT4,oCNT5,CLOCK_50,Done);

input [1:0] KEY; 
input [9:0] SW;
input      CLOCK_50;


output [3:0] oCNT0,oCNT1,oCNT2,oCNT3,oCNT4,oCNT5;
output wire Done;

wire EN0,EN1,EN2,EN3,EN4,EN5;
wire [3:0] oCNT0, oCNT1,oCNT2,oCNT3,oCNT4,oCNT5;
wire [18:0] oCNT;

assign Done = ({oCNT5,oCNT4,oCNT3,oCNT2,oCNT1,oCNT0}==(24'b000000000000000000000000)) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;   

assign iRSTn=(SW[7]&~SW[6]&~KEY[0]) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;  

reg start;

reg [26:0] press_counter;
reg long_press;

reg button_pressed;

//This part of the code implements logic to perform two different functions using a single key.
always @(posedge CLOCK_50 or negedge iRSTn) begin
    if (!iRSTn) begin
        press_counter <= 0;
        button_pressed <= 0;
        long_press <= 0;
        start <= 0;
    end else begin
        if (KEY[1]) begin
            press_counter <= press_counter + 1;
            button_pressed <= 1;

            // 2sec over
            if (press_counter >27'd100000000) begin
                long_press <= 1;
            end
        end else if (button_pressed) begin
            if (long_press) begin
                start <= start; // Preset
            end else begin
                start <= ~start; //Toggle
            end
            // reset
            press_counter <= 0;
            button_pressed <= 0;
            long_press <= 0;
        end
    end
end


COUNTER_LAB
#(.n(23),.k(5000000))
U_Counter_ms_gen(
        .iRSTn(iRSTn),
        .iCLK(CLOCK_50),
        .iEN(start&Done),
        .oEN(EN0),
        .oCNT(oCNT)
); // 5M Count

COUNTER_PRESET_DOWN
#(.n(4),.k(10))
COUNTER_timer_ms(.iCLK(CLOCK_50), .iRSTn(iRSTn), .iPRSTn(1'b0), .iEN(EN0), .iDATA_Preset(4'b0000), .oEN(EN1), .oCNT(oCNT0));  // ms

COUNTER_PRESET_DOWN
#(.n(4),.k(10))
COUNTER_timer_s0(.iCLK(CLOCK_50), .iRSTn(iRSTn), .iPRSTn(1'b0), .iEN(EN1), .iDATA_Preset(4'b0000), .oEN(EN2), .oCNT(oCNT1));  // seconds (units)

COUNTER_PRESET_DOWN
#(.n(3),.k(6))
COUNTER_timer_s1(.iCLK(CLOCK_50), .iRSTn(iRSTn), .iPRSTn((~KEY[1] & ~long_press) & (SW[5:4] == 2'b00) & (SW[7:6] == 2'b10)), .iEN(EN2), .iDATA_Preset(SW[3:0]), .oEN(EN3), .oCNT(oCNT2));  // seconds (tens)

COUNTER_PRESET_DOWN
#(.n(4),.k(10))
COUNTER_timer_m0(.iCLK(CLOCK_50), .iRSTn(iRSTn), .iPRSTn((~KEY[1] & ~long_press) & (SW[5:4] == 2'b01) & (SW[7:6] == 2'b10)), .iEN(EN3), .iDATA_Preset(SW[3:0]), .oEN(EN4), .oCNT(oCNT3));  // minutes (units)

COUNTER_PRESET_DOWN
#(.n(3),.k(6))
COUNTER_timer_m1(.iCLK(CLOCK_50), .iRSTn(iRSTn), .iPRSTn((~KEY[1] & ~long_press) & (SW[5:4] == 2'b10) & (SW[7:6] == 2'b10)), .iEN(EN4), .iDATA_Preset(SW[2:0]), .oEN(EN5), .oCNT(oCNT4));  // minutes (tens)

COUNTER_PRESET_DOWN
#(.n(4),.k(13))
COUNTER_timer_h(.iCLK(CLOCK_50), .iRSTn(iRSTn), .iPRSTn((~KEY[1] & ~long_press) & (SW[5:4] == 2'b11) & (SW[7:6] == 2'b10)), .iEN(EN5), .iDATA_Preset(SW[3:0]), .oEN(), .oCNT(oCNT5));  // hours

endmodule

//Timer Counter
module COUNTER_PRESET_DOWN(
    iCLK,
    iRSTn,
    iPRSTn,
    iEN,
    iDATA_Preset,
    oEN, //roll-over signal
    oCNT
);

parameter n=4;
parameter k=10;

input iCLK,iRSTn,iPRSTn,iEN;
input [n-1:0] iDATA_Preset;
output [n-1:0] oCNT;
output oEN;

reg [n-1:0] oCNT;

assign oEN =((oCNT == 0) && (iEN == 1'b1)) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0;

always@(posedge iCLK or negedge iRSTn)
begin
    if(~iRSTn)
    begin
        oCNT <= 0;
    end
    else if(iPRSTn)
    begin 
        oCNT <= iDATA_Preset;
    end
    else if(iEN)
    begin
        if(oCNT==0)
        begin
            oCNT<=k-1;
        end
        else
        begin
            oCNT<=oCNT-1;
        end
    end
    else
    begin 
        oCNT<=oCNT;
    end
end

endmodule


How do you set the timer to 1 minute, for example?

One potential problem is how you drive your asynchronous reset iRSTn:
assign iRSTn=(SW[7]&~SW[6]&~KEY[0]) ? 1'b0 : 1'b1;  

Since it is combinational logic of 3 signals, the reset is subject to glitches.
Consider changing your code to use a synchronous reset:
always @(posedge CLOCK_50) begin

